# New error message box is easy to miss

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, editor

In my answer to [Is it possible for many domain names to share one IP address?](https://superuser.com/questions/577070) I wanted to include a link to the IP for superuser.com to show how shared hosting and accessing by IP's did not work, however when I attempted to add a link to `198.252.206.16` it circled the box in red and put the popup window on the right.

[image]

I totally missed the popup window when trying to figure out why it was erroring out. In fact I was typing this up as a bug report (for not showing any message at all) and I did not spot the box until I reproduced the issue and was taking the screenshot.

The red error text below the message box was much more visible then this new popup and I feel that it should be switched back.

Comment: That error message could also be hard to understand. Nonnumeric domain? Code block? I can imagine a lot of people being confused by that.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167914/put-the-error-message-above-or-below-not-next-to-the-editor and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167588/make-error-notifications-in-posts-more-obvious-visible

Answer (score 1):

We've added a wiggle to the error message to help you find it in the background. Hopefully this addresses any remaining issues with visibility.

Comment: There's a gap between "arrow" and box in motion on Firefox 20 on OS X.